# Django - limit the choices of a choice field in a form

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm having a problem with a choice field in Django. I need to have a form to add order movements to a work orders.

These are the choices in choices.py

```
STATUS_CHOICES = (
    (1, ("Orden Creada")),
    (2, ("En Tienda Asociada")),
    (3, ("Recibida en Cuyotek")),
    (4, ("En Mesa de Trabajo")),
    (5, ("Trabajo completado")),
    (6, ("Sin Solución")),
    (7, ("Lista para retirar en Cuyotek")),
    (8, ("Lista para retirar en Tienda Asociada")),
    (9, ("Es necesario contactar al cliente")),
    (10, ("En espera de Repuestos")),
    (20, ("ENTREGADA")),
)
```

And I need to limit the choices to show only "8 and 20" if the user is not staff.

This is the model in models.py

```
class OrderMovements(models.Model):
    fk_workorder = models.ForeignKey(WorkOrder)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=1)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.fk_workorder)
```

And this the form in forms.py

```
class AddMovementForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = OrderMovements
        fields = ['status']

    def clean_status(self):
        status = self.cleaned_data.get('status')
        return status
```

I can't find info about how to make this filter.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to define an `__init__()` method in your form class which takes `is_staff` as an argument. `is_staff` can be a boolean value.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    is_staff = kwargs.pop('is_staff')
    super(AddMovementForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if is_staff:
        self.fields['status'].choices = STAFF_STATUS_CHOICES
    else:
        self.fields['status'].choices = STATUS_CHOICES
```

When you initialize your form, you can do

```
AddMovementForm(is_staff=True)  # or
AddMovementForm(is_staff=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `__init__()` method of your form, you can change the choices of `status` field.

```
class AddMovementForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = OrderMovements
        fields = ['status']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(AddMovementForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if not self.user.is_staff:
            limited_choices = [(choice[0], choice[1]) for choice in STATUS_CHOICES if choice[0] == 8 or choice[0] == 20]
            self.fields['status'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=limited_choices)])

    def clean_status(self):
        status = self.cleaned_data.get('status')
        return status
```

You have to pass the `request.user` to your form as well. Notice that this is a rough idea, nothing tested, but you should get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for your tip, i go to study mor of this because i think is going to be very usefull but i can't make it work hehe. Need to learn more!