# Add extra metadata to model info Django returns for OPTIONS

Tags: django

In my Django application I have a list of `Event_Type`s that users can subscribe to. Pretty simple with:

`event_type = models.CharField(choices=EVENT_TYPES, max_length=128)`

And the UI gets a list of available event types when it calls OPTIONS. The challenge is that certain levels of permissions open up additional choices. So the UI sees a bunch of event types that are unavailable to that user. It's not a security concern to know that the options are there, but it requires per-`event_type` filtering in the UI, which I would like to rather be driven by the OPTIONS. Is there a way to manually add metadata to what OPTIONS returns?

Comment: Can you post your form that you're passing to your template? And what do you mean by `OPTIONS`?

Comment: sounds to me that you're looking for something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32016091/1666143

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django - limit the choices of a choice field in a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32015509/django-limit-the-choices-of-a-choice-field-in-a-form)

Comment: HTTP has various calls (GET, POST, PUT, etc). A useful one supported by Django is OPTIONS which describes the model. I'm using an Angular UI rather than Django's forms.