# Limit the choices of a choice field in the model class

Tags: django

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32016091/7522891) shows how to limit a choice field in **the form**. However, I have a choice field with options that should *never* be shown to the user. Hence, **I want to limit the choice field options in the model class** to adhere to the DRY principle and to prevent myself from forgetting to adding code in future forms.

Here is a simple example:

```
UNIT_TYPES = Choices(
    (1, 'APARTMENT', 'Apartment'),
    (2, 'TOWNHOUSE', 'Townhouse'),
    (3, 'SINGLE_FAMILY', 'Single-family home'),
    (4, 'OTHER', 'Other') # Never show in any views
)
```

For this particular example, only the first three choices should be shown to the user in forms whereas the fourth will only be set on the backend if certain conditions are met.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe use a custom manager ? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers

Comment: @Benbb96 I updated the question with an example. Can you please provide some code on how to achieve this limitation with a custom manager using this example?

Comment: Ok I can give it a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a custom manager which will always exclude one of your choices :

```
APARTMENT = 1
TOWNHOUSE = 2
SINGLE_FAMILY = 3
OTHER = 4
UNIT_TYPES = (
    (APARTMENT, 'Apartment'),
    (TOWNHOUSE, 'Townhouse'),
    (SINGLE_FAMILY, 'Single-family home'),
    (OTHER, 'Other')
)


class CustomManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().exclude(unit_type=OTHER)


class Model(models.Model):
    unit_type = models.IntegerField(
        choices=UNIT_TYPES,
        validators=[MinValueValidator(APARTMENT), MaxValueValidator(OTHER)]
    )

    objects = CustomManager()
```

Answer (score 2):

I would create another set of choices within your models.py file for those that are hidden, e.g.

```
UNIT_TYPES = Choices(
    (1, 'APARTMENT', 'Apartment'),
    (2, 'TOWNHOUSE', 'Townhouse'),
    (3, 'SINGLE_FAMILY', 'Single-family home'),
)

HIDDEN_TYPES = Choices(
    (4, 'OTHER', 'Other') # Never show in any views
)
```

You should be able to set the model choices as `UNIT_TYPES + HIDDEN_TYPES` and then access `HIDDEN_TYPES` within your form file. With reference to the answer you linked, you can customised the `__init__()` function to set the choices based on `UNIT_TYPES` and ignore `HIDDEN_TYPES` completely.

If there are any other places within your application that a user might see these choices, then you will need to take care to exclude the hidden types. As far as I'm aware, there isn't a way of making this more dynamic - the model `__init__()` method doesn't have access to the `request` object which you would tell you which user is involved.